# Unable to save the result in a variable

Tags: python-2.7, list

In the below code if I simply print Name_item then the output will be

```
['ABCD', 'ABCD.@abcd.com']
```

but when I tried to save this result in a variable say 's' then the output is None. Why this is happening?

Please help.

```
Name = 'ABCD'

Email = 'ABCD.@abcd.com'

Name_item = Name.split(',')

Email_item = Email.split(',')

s = Name_item.extend(Email.split(','))

print s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.extend` doesn't return a value, thus `s` is emtpy.

The list `Name_item` is exended:

```
>>> Name_item
['ABCD', 'ABCD.@abcd.com']
```

> Return Value
>
> This method does not return any value but add the content to existing list.

see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm